# Parsing JSON from healtcheck endpoint with Prometheus/Grafana?

Tags: grafana, prometheus, cadvisor, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

My application provides an endpoint `http://localhost:5000/health` which returns a JSON like this:

**HTTP 200**

```
{
  "statuses": {
    "component_1": "up",
    "component_2": "up",
    "component_3": "up",
    "component_4": "up"
  }
}
```

In case of an error it returns:

**HTTP 500**

```
{
  "statuses": {
    "component_1": "up",
    "component_2": "down",
    "component_3": "up",
    "component_4": "down"
  }
}
```

This endpoint is used as a Docker `HEALTHCHECK` in the `Dockerfile` for that application image.

Can I use Grafana with a Prometheus data source to query this endpoint and show one status panel with "UP/DOWN" for each of the components?

My first thought was using `cAdvisor` but I can't find a metric which allows extracting the Docker container status.

Comment: You may use this exporter (not tested) https://github.com/kawamuray/prometheus-json-exporter. It maps json to metrics and can handle text matching.